# Turn off scientific notation visualcode (scipen not working in R profile?)

Tags: r, output, notation

I have downloaded R studios, and R extension in visualcode.
in the R profile file i have typed in
options(scipen=999) and saved.

When i run my code in visualcode it dosent get rid of scientific notation in my output barchart. Why?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set the `scientific` argument of `format` function to `FALSE` in `scale_y_continous`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you i will try. :) I think my problem might be that i did not download languageserver in R. Problem is when i use install.packages("languageserver") it seem to not install correctly. It says there where 22 warnings? Do you know what´s wrong with that. I have R 3.4.4 and i think languageserver is good for that version.

Comment: where do i find scale_y_continous? :)

Comment: It is in `ggplot2`. Just add to your code if you want to change y axis otherwise `scale_x_continous`! :-) See here <https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html>

Comment: See here how to ask a good question! It raises the change of getting a good answer bei almost 100% <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: Thank you :) I think i understand a bit more know. I´m really bad, sorry. trying to learn. but when i install ggplot package with install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE) i get 32 warnings. Why cant i install it is it because i couldent install languageserver either? :) install.packages('ggplot2') dident work either.

Comment: You're welcome. Take your time. Just never give up.

Comment: Thank you. install.packages('ggplot2') gave me 32 warnings why can´t i install the package? :)

Comment: Warnings should not avoid to install. Try `library(ggplot2)` and it should work. Then it depends on the warnings. Read them and decide.

Comment: Still struggling ahah :D Where do i change scipen in jupyter notebook? Think that will be easiest. But there is no options file existing in jupyter notebook :O so i don´t know where to go to change this scipen thing. i know it should be options(scipen=999), but i don´t know where to change it. i can´t just write it in my python code either because since no options map i get yellow line when i write options. so in what file do i change scipen in jupyter notebook?? :) Actually in R map there is options file, and i saw scipen there, but that dosen´t change it for jupyter notebook?Nothing happened